# how to iterate through the list, fetching each possible pair of values?

Tags: python, list, iteration, generator

How can I walk through the `list` (of numbers) and fetch every possible pair of its values?

Example (java):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    for(int j = i+1; j < 5; j++)
        print(i, j); // 01, 02, 03, 04, 12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 34
```

My problem is that the list is fetched via generator function, hence it is lazy. In addition, it may be extremely large so keeping all pairs in memory is more than desperate solution.

*So the final question* - how can one achieve the same behavior in python, keeping in mind that memory is limited? Also complexity should not more than `O(N^2)` where `N` is the length of the `list`.

Comment: what you mean exactly by *every possible pair of its values*? whats the expected format of that pairs? can you add an input and a desire output?

Comment: I mean unordered 2-tuple of values, printed in comment in the java example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `itertools.combinations`:

```
list(itertools.combinations(range(5), 2))
Out[7]: 
[(0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (0, 4),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (3, 4)]
```

Or to make string from pairs:

```
[''.join(str(i) for i in p) for p in itertools.combinations(range(5), 2)]
Out[8]: ['01', '02', '03', '04', '12', '13', '14', '23', '24', '34']
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually you want the combinations, you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function :

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations(range(5),2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

And if you want to concatenate the result you can convert the elements to string then `join` them :

```
>>> [''.join(map(str,i)) for i in combinations(range(5),2)]
['01', '02', '03', '04', '12', '13', '14', '23', '24', '34']
```

Also as a more efficient way for get the expected output you can use a string contain all the digits from 0 to 5 :

```
>>> from string import digits
>>> [''.join(i) for i in combinations(digits[:5],2)]
['01', '02', '03', '04', '12', '13', '14', '23', '24', '34']
```

Comment: Cheers for you, for not over-iterate (listify it, than iterate) an iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Like so (with no libraries):

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

newlst = [(y,z) for y in lst for z in lst]
output = set(['%s%s' % (x[0], x[1]) for x in newlst])
```

Or, as a one-liner (ie. unreadable):

```
set(['%s%s' % (x[0], x[1]) for x in [(y, z) for y in lst for z in lst]])
```

Comment: This does not produce the expected output, since your solution generates all permutations of 5 elements over 2 positions (with repetitions).

Answer (score 2):

I think we're all overlooking the most simple solution...

```
from itertools import combinations
for x in combinations(range(5), 2):
    print x
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
from itertools import combination
>>>[''.join(map(str, i)) for i in combinations(range(5), 2)]
['01', '02', '03', '04', '12', '13', '14', '23', '24', '34']
```